# Microsoft(R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler has stopped working

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a windows application including N number of projects.

At the time of building that application i get  the above issue.

The detail of this error is:-

Problem signature:

```
 Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
  Application Name: CL.exe
  Application Version:  15.0.30729.1
  Application Timestamp:    488ef23c
  Fault Module Name:    c2.dll
  Fault Module Version: 15.0.30729.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   488ef261
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000e4aeb
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
```

What may be the cause of this error.

Comment: That's a compiler crash. I'm afraid only Microsoft can answer that one. I would suggest you forward a crash report to them.

Comment: Does this happen when you compile one specific project and all other projects compile well? Why have you tagged the question with C#-4.0, is it C++/CLI project? If so, then use CLR or CLI or other more relevant tags. Another thing - which version of VS are you using? What extra plugins do you have? Have you mixed some of the VS versions or do you have just one? Have you tried some tricks to i.e. force building of VS2013 projects under VS2008, etc?

Comment: cl v15 is visual c++ 2008, windows 6.1 is win7, that's definitely a supported mix, so you need to hassle Microsoft.

Comment: And one last guess: fetch ProcMon from microsoft/technet/SysInternals, set it up to listen for path or process name equal to "cl.exe" (whatever works), run the monitor, then run the offending build, and then stop the monitor when the build crashes. Look through the logs near their end and find the last "process start" of cl.exe and peek its commandline parameters. There will be some source files listed that the CL.exe has been compiling. Inspect each of those files, check if they are correct and undamaged (no binaries, no strange characters, etc.). If you see any PCHs used, regenerate them.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl +1, but please phrase such requests so that the tag [tag:cli] does not get used incorrectly; the correct tag is [tag:c++-cli].

Comment: @Angew: you're right, but it's too late and I can't edit the comment now :/

Comment: If i build some projects individually then other projects are successfully build.
But while building a particular project i am getting this issue.
I am using VS 2008(.NET FRAMEWORK 3.5)